# Development Logs and Testing for OpenLocate

Tags: android

I'm hoping to use the [OpenLocate](https://github.com/OpenLocate/openlocate-android) library to help post location data in my application. I've been trying to test that it is working before I start posting events over HTTP calls sent somewhere.

I want to verify two main things

1. Events are being collected at the frequency I expect
2. Events are being stored in the database

I've verified that OpenLocate is tracking when I run the app by printing out the `OpenLocate.getInstance().isTracking()` flag. I've also tried using Stetho to inspect my package to see if I could read the db, but unfortunately nothing shows up.

If anyone has some experience with OpenLocate and can give me some info that would be great.

Comment: Did you managed to work it out? I also see on my Android app that the open locate is running, but no locations are being posted to my server

Comment: I never figured this out @Asaf, I opened an issue on Github https://github.com/OpenLocate/openlocate-android/issues/67. They said to inspect the db but I couldn't find a database that was being created by OpenLocate to inspect. Shortly after we transitioned solutions and didn't need to use OpenLocate anymore. It's an interesting project though and I'd love to see some better debug tools. Let me know if you find anything.

Comment: "Shortly after we transitioned solutions" - you mean that you found an alternative to OpenLocate or developed something on your own?

Comment: We decided to just roll our own, we didn't need everything that OpenLocate provided. And we didn't necessarily need it to be stored locally all the time so we decided to work with a custom implementation. 

I think OpenLocate looks like the best option if you need everything it provides. But I thought when I was using it it looked like I would have to work with the source and add a handful of features on as well.